# How to set footer in android

Tags: android, android-layout

How to set footer in android on each page

I have used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:background="@color/mcolor"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_gravity="fill">

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/iconbtn" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:src="@drawable/all_icon_138" 
           android:layout_marginRight="4px" 
           android:layout_gravity="fill" 
           android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@color/mcolor"
             android:layout_marginLeft="60px" 
             android:layout_marginTop="12px" android:saveEnabled="true">
</ImageButton>
<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
     android:id="@+id/label" 
     android:textColor="@color/mbcolor" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:scrollbars="vertical" 
     android:layout_marginBottom="30px"
     android:layout_marginTop="30px" 
     android:textSize="12px"
     android:layout_marginRight="30px"
     android:layout_marginLeft="130px"></TextView>
<LinearLayout android:layout_marginTop="50dip" 
    android:gravity="bottom"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
     <ImageButton android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/newfox_footer_320"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="false" 
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="false" android:layout_marginLeft="190px" android:layout_marginRight="2px">
            </ImageButton></LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It is showing 6 images of footer after each `TextView`.
How do I set it?

Comment: check out this  :

[Add footer to list view][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-footer-in-list-view/4265324#4265324

Answer (score 2):

its is not clear what do you exactly want but i assume you want a footer in a layout.

use a framelayout as you main layout with

```
width = fillparent
height = fillparent
```

take another framelayout set the gravity to bottom.
add views to this framelayout. 
this is your footer.

Answer (score 1):

Make the root view of your xml Layout a RelativeLayout.
Then the view you want as footer, or his parent (the one who is direct child of the root view element: RelativeLayout) needs to have this attribute:
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Answer (score 0):

You've used LinearLayout for footer, so you can check out [stackoverflow: footer for linear layout in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4743923/1344509)