# How to add a footer in ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, footer

I am developing an application,In my application,I am using Listview for displaying data using dom parsing,I want to footer in listview,when i click footer additional more data add to list view,I attached image,i would like that design and process,please refer image1 and imgae2.I mention footer in red rectangle

**Fig1-Footer like "More News"**
[image]

[image]

Fig2-Add additional 10 record added in listview

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Create a footer view layout consisting of  text that you want to set as footer and then try

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
ListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Layout for footer could be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="7dip"
    android:paddingBottom="7dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView 
        android:text="@string/footer_text_1" 
        android:id="@+id/footer_1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="14dip" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity class could be:

```
public class MyListActivty extends ListActivity {
    private Context context = null;
    private ListView list = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        //code to set adapter to populate list
        View footerView =  ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
        list.addFooterView(footerView);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good, but what if you want the footer to be FIXED on the screen, rather than only visible when scrolled to the bottom?  And what if you want the footer to be visible even when the list is EMPTY?  See full question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353701/fixed-and-always-visible-footer-below-listfragment.

Comment: I had some problems making this code work and solved them. Here is what the addFooterView() documentation states `NOTE: Call this before calling setAdapter. This is so ListView can wrap the supplied cursor with one that will also account for header and footer views.`

Comment: @gcl1 In that case that is not a footer, just an ordinary element in your layout that is below the list view. Just, you know, put it below the list view?

Comment: Just a shout out to @demonsten: if you call setAdapter() before adding the views, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: if there is no data in adapter then footer is not attaching (showing). so how can we display footer even if there is no data in adapter ? thanks

Comment: @demosten You have no idea how helpful that comment was. Was having all kinds of weird InvalidCastException errors, telling me to use HeaderViewListAdapater and whatnot, when my actual problem was not adding my headers and footers /before/ setting my adapter. Thanks again.

Comment: Here is a workaround for those getting a ClassCastException despite setting your adapter after adding the footer  - a one-liner which wraps your adapter and casts it to HeaderViewListAdapter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10819996/1959110

Answer (score 10):

Answers here are a bit outdated. Though the code remains the same there are some changes in the behavior.

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView footerView = (TextView) ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null, false);
        getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.news)));
    }
}
```

Info about `addFooterView()` method

> Add a fixed view to appear at the bottom of the list. If `addFooterView()` is called more than once, the views will appear in the order they were added. Views added using this call can take focus if they want.

Most of the answers above stress very important point -

> `addFooterView()` must be called before calling `setAdapter()`.This is so ListView can wrap the supplied cursor with one that will also account for header and footer views.

From Kitkat this has changed.

> Note: When first introduced, this method could only be called before setting the adapter with setAdapter(ListAdapter). Starting with KITKAT, this method may be called at any time. If the ListView's adapter does not extend HeaderViewListAdapter, it will be wrapped with a supporting instance of WrapperListAdapter.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29)

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a very old question, but I googled my way here and found the answer provided not 100% satisfying, because as gcl1 mentioned - this way the footer is not really a footer to the screen - it's just an "add-on" to the list.

Bottom line - for others who may google their way here - I found the following suggestion here: [Fixed and always visible footer below ListFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353701/fixed-and-always-visible-footer-below-listfragment)

Try doing as follows, where the emphasis is on the button (or any footer element) listed first in the XML - and then the list is added as "layout_above":

```
<RelativeLayout>

<Button android:id="@+id/footer" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/> 
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" **android:layout_above**="@id/footer"> <!-- the list -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

If the ListView is a child of the ListActivity:

```
getListView().addFooterView(
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null)
);
```

(inside onCreate())

Answer (score 2):

The activity in which you want to add listview footer  and i have also generate an event on listview footer click.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
         {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ListView  list_of_f = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_f);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_view, null);  // i have open a webview on the listview footer

            RelativeLayout  layoutFooter = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutFooter);

            list_of_f.addFooterView(view);

        }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dept_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dept_nav" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_of_f"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dept_nav"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this Question, best answer not work for me. After that i found this method to show listview footer,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup footerView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_layout,listView,false);
listView.addFooterView(footerView, null, false);
```

And create new layout call footer_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Done"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:background="#d6cf55"
        android:padding="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If not work refer this article [hear](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-listview-footer.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a stackLayout, inside of this layout you can put a list a frame, for example:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}"
                       CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                       HasUnevenRows="True">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell >
                            <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Image, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Button Text="More"></Button>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
```

this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
   // adding a footer to list as Log Out
    val view: View =
        (getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater).inflate(
            R.layout.logout_menu, null, false
        )
    //  footer onClick
    view.setOnClickListener {
        doLogout()
        binding.drawerLayout.close()

    }
    expandableListView.addFooterView(view)
```