# Android footer after listview

Tags: android, button, footer

I am facing a problem of application crash when I wanted to display a footer button underneath the list view. I have attached my xml code and activity code herewith. Any help will be highly appreciated.

ContactListActivity.java

```
  public class ContactListActivity1 extends ListActivity {
    static ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();

     ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ContactList1 contactList = this.getContacts();
        ArrayAdapter<Contact1> adapter = new ContactAdapter1(this,
                contactList.getContacts());


          // LoadMore button
            Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
            btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");

        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contactlistitem,null);

        lv.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);



    }
```

And my XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"


>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDisplayName"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        >

</TextView>


     <ImageView

android:id="@+id/contact_image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"


/>



   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/contactList1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtDisplayName"
    />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your Logcat with error..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You made a mistake -

- You're extending `ListActivity` so where is `lv = getListView()` in your code.
- Or, you should give `list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);` after your `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in your `onCreate`

Because, extending `ListActivity` these are important. It seems not proper with your code. You better have look at this example [How to add a footer in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4265228/940096) before starting your application.

Comment: `setContentView(...)` is not mandatory if you are extending Activity with ListActivity, is it?

Comment: Just an addition, for it to work with a ListActivity, your listview should have the following id, `@android:id/list`

Comment: @SpK regarding your edit, getting a listview like that will break the layout structure, it'll have to be a child of the inflated view, i.e `v`, so the code should be `(ListView) v.findViewById(...)`. In any case the simplest way is to use `setContentView(..)` and then `getListView()`.