# Add a button in bottom of listview when the listview is empty (using ListActivity)

Tags: android, listview, layout

I using extends ListActivity to show the empty message when the list are empty.
Below is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"    >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1.0">
    </ListView>

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:text="No Items! Please Add!"/> 

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"        
        android:text="Add Item" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is the button can only appear when there have item in list, but can't appear when the list is empty. How can the button appear when the list are empty?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4265324/1434631

Comment: You can dynamically check if there exist element to show in the list and if not, then set the visibility as GONE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i'm not trying to add the footer but just need to add a button. I change the xml as below then problem solved. Thanks everyone.^^

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1.0"
          android:layout_above="@+id/bAdd">
    </ListView>


    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_above="@+id/bAdd"
               android:text="No Items! Please Add!"/> 

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAdd"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"        
        android:text="Add Item" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

At first check `getCount()`. If `getCount()` return 0, then the `visibility` of button should be visible otherwise `'invisible'` or `'gone'`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the the `android` `tag` `android:visible`  `buttons` codes in `xml` reference id you can set

```
button.setVisibility(View.Visible or View.inVisible) based on your requirement.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a footer view layout inside your listview's layout.

```
View footer = ((LayoutInflater) ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer, null, false);

ListView.addFooterView(footer);
```

Also check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353701/fixed-and-always-visible-footer-below-listfragment).

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the ListView doesn't have items in it by doing

```
listview.getAdapter().isEmpty
```

If it is, set the button's visibility to `gone`. Otherwise, `visible`