# Button at bottom of ListView only working in Eclipse designer

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to place a Button at the bottom of a ListActivity. 
The following works perfectly in the Eclipse designer but not when I launch the app of my phone or AVD.

Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_New" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_New"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Button appears correctly in the designer
[image: Button appears correctly in the designer]

Button not appearing on my phone or AVD
[image: Button not appearing on my phone or AVD]

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the button BEFORE the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_New"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_New" >
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

so the layout inflater can 'see' which view the list have to be on top of

Comment: This had no effect. The Button still shows in the Eclipse designer but not on my phone or AVD. And yes I made sure to uninstall the app from the phone and AVD to verify the modification actually took place.

Answer (score 0):

you may add a footer to your ListView. you can use the example provided in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-footer-in-list-view/4265324#4265324)

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater)      
ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
ListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Answer (score 0):

this one is completely my mistake. My Activity was extending SherlockListActivity, instead of SherlockActivity. So of course the Button wasn't displaying.

Thanks for all your help, 
Cathal