# How to use a different layout in each ActionBar tab (Android)

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an application which uses the Android ActionBar and has three tabs. I am using a fragment container to switch in my different ListFragments, but for one of the tab's I'd also like a button at the bottom of the layout and a couple of TextViews which hold a summary of the data in the list. I have implmeneted this elsewhere in the application as a FragmentActivity and ListFragment.

I wondered if there was any way of defining a layout for one tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the layout xml you're inflating ListFragment with then put the extra views along side the list element. You can use `onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)` in the FragmentActivity to track if your special case tab is selected then push a flag inside a bundle to the what instantiates your fragment class to then indicate it needs to inflate a different layout in `onCreateView()`.

Say you might have this for that layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adding TextViews or a Button below the ListView here works (kinda, they get pushed off the bottom of the screen in this exact example).  Depending on how you do the layout holding your ListView you can either get the new items persistent at the bottom of the screen while the list scrolls (RelativeLayout holding everything, a linearlayout holding the text/button, and `android:layout_above="@+id/idOfThatLinearLayout"` added as an attribute of the ListView).  Or alternatively you could [do something similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4265324/1305064) with addFooterView() to get these new items to actually scroll *with* the list as if they were the last item at the bottom.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. At the moment I have a fragment container which is filled with a ListFragment which uses a simple cursor adapter with it's own layout for each row.

Comment: The class of that ListFragment should start with a line like "onCreateView(... )" and at the start of that method should be a call to the layout inflater for the ListFragment.  This is what I'm referring to above.