# Add item to List Scroll without inflating it in getView

Tags: java, android

I am not sure if that is even possible but is there a way we can add an item to the listView scroll which is not a part of ListView i.e header and footer

for example I have a list of name with the title Image and Submit Button but I don't want to inflate it in getView method.

Comment: why do you want to do this ?

Comment: I am trying to add a buttons at the top of the list and at bottom of the list in the scroll I just want to know if there is a way we can add header and footer to the list scroll without having to inflate different views

Comment: AFAIK there isn't and if there is that would be a hack. IMHO you should use a Relativelayout and put the two buttons on top and bottom and these would overlay your listview and would be visible or invisible based on your choice , I am sure this could be done.

Comment: well I am well acquinted with the that was just looking for a smart way out but thanks alot for help.

Comment: Look this post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-footer-in-list-view

It can help you.