# How to set Button just below the ListView?

Tags: android, layout

I want to create a layout where a listview always show the data above the bottom button. How to do that. Here are the different options given below
I option

```
item1
item2
button
empty space
empty space
empty space
empty space
empty space
empty space
```

II option

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
item6
item7
item8
button
```

III option

```
item3
item4
item5
item6
item7
item8
item9
item10
button
```

How to realise this layout with list and button? For example, if I have 15 items than access to items by scroll (ScrollView solve this problem) and button is visible.

Comment: what you want to do??? and what you are trying to say, can you please explain in brief...

Comment: IV option: I have dynamicaly changing count of TextView and Button. When TextView count more than screen size (if I use LinearLayout and some count of TextView, Button as childs) than Button doesn't visible. How to solve this?!

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question. Create a layout with a `ListView` and create another layout with a button. Now add the `Button` layout as a footer of this `ListView` layout.
 ListView Layout will be like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the Button Layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can dynamically add footer in a `ListView`. It is perfect solution for you. Checkout the answer [How to add footer in Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-footer-in-list-view)

For your purpose I can re-write the code as a sample. Please check it and play with it.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutOption1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutOption2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 4" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutOption3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 4" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

In your activity class get the id of each layout option and setVisibility for your purpose. In your requirement I wrote this code for your. Thanks.

Comment: For some resons I can't use ListView. Please, can you explain how to realize the same with ScrollView? Thanks.

Comment: ScrollView is not good solution for this specific problem. I don't want to encourage you to do that using ScrollView. Anyway you can use ScrollView for this purpose but you have to maintain extra hassle for that. So try to learn how to use ListView.

Comment: I know how to use ListView. But I have near some TextView CheckBox and need onItemClick and onItemChecked events. So ListView is not good for this.

Comment: Can you determine how many data will be showed in each option before loading it.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: No I don't get the answer(

Answer (score 0):

If you want use ScrollView try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/LastButton">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 1" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 2" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 3" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 4" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 5" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 6" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 7" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LastButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Last Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LastButton nead android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in order to stay visible when LinearLayout grows.

Comment: My button should be near text... Thanks for try)