# How to get a shadow effect at end of the ListView in android?

Tags: android, listview, shadow, drawerlayout

I am trying to get a shadow effect at the end of my ListView which is placed inside a DrawerLayout. I have a png image for the shadow effect. I just want to know how to place it. I tried creating  a view and placing this image as a background image, but the wholw layout gets the shadow. My xml file is below and please guide me step by step what to do.

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />




<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>

<View
        android:id="@+id/vieworange"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:background="@drawable/menushade"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add

```
 list.addFooterView(footerView);
```

and insert shadow image in footer view for details [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-a-footer-in-listview)!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to place that PNG shadow image as a background of your listview. i.e.

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:background="@drawable/profile_background"
    />
```

Comment: I want a black background for the Listview and the shadow effect at the end of the listview. Setting android:backround just gives me the shadow and not the black color

Comment: Ok, so for that you need to create one 9 patch image with shadow and black background .so that you can set it as a background which will serves both purpose black background and  shadow