# Display footer in expandablelistview even if there is no data in adapter

Tags: android, expandablelistview, footer

Well, I succeed to add footer on expandablelistview and it's working fine if there is some data in adapter; however, footer is not displaying if there are no records in adapter.

So is that possible to add (display) footer even if there is no data in adapter?

I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/4265324/1199602 solution.

P.S : I already added footer before setting adapter to expandablelistview.

Thanks in Advance. As always answer will be surely appreciated.:)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a dummy blank data to adapter.

Comment: +1 Good trick and already tried dear.but cant do that for some other reason. (like if there is any data in LV then i have to do some operations and also need to manage adapter - after notifying data)