# How do you align a button to the bottom of a ListView that sticks to the bottom even after deleting a row?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button

I'm trying to create a layout that contains a `ListView` with a button underneath it, and also make it so that the button 'sticks' to the bottom of the ListView, even when I add or delete a row from the ListView.

With the layout code below, when I add a new row to the list, the button 'moves' to its correct location right beneath the bottom of the ListView.  So that works fine.

The problem is when I delete a row from the ListView, the button stays where it is and doesn't 'move up' so that it sticks to the bottom of the ListView.  When I rotate the device and it recreates the view, the button does in fact move up, but I'd like it to automatically move up when a row is deleted.

Here is the code I have now:

```
<LinearLayout   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >                

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />           

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/add_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**SOLUTION:**

The solution was to create a small layout file that contains just the button, then add it as the footer of the ListView programatically.

Inside my fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 

    ...

    View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_footer, null, false);

    addButton = (ImageButton) footerView.findViewById(R.id.addButton);

    listView.addFooterView(footerView);

    data = getListViewData();

    adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), data);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ...

}
```

listview_footer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ImageButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/add_button" />
```

The listview_footer.xml just contains the button, and no layout.

Now, when I delete a row from the `ListView`, the button moves up to 'stick' to the bottom of the ListView.  And as before, when I add a row to the ListView, the button moves down below it.

Comment: Try to add this button as footer.

Comment: or use relative layout and use align parent bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add button to the footer of the listview.

```
View footerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.footer, null);
listview.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Make an xml file for the footer view in which you will add a button as per your UI needs.

Footer.xml may look like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:padding="5dip">

 <Button android:id="@+id/previous"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-a-footer-in-listview) may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >                

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />           

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below= "@+id/listView"
        android:src="@drawable/add_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This won't compile because of the circular dependency (ListView above button and Button below ListView).

Comment: @JDJ did you check it?

Comment: That made the ListView appear again, but the button doesn't move up when I delete a row.

Comment: Try changing the height of listview to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 1):

User `RelativeLayout` instead. Add  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to Image Button and `android:layout_above="@+id/addButton"` to listView

```
    <RelativeLayout   
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >                

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/addButton"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>           

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/add_button" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_weight` doesn't work in RelativeLayout.

Comment: For some reason, the ListView is invisible with this layout.

Comment: It's still invisible for some reason.

Comment: ListView is not visible because height is set to 0dp

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation where I wanted a button to always be in the bottom right of my list, and there would be many deletion/additions to the list. I used a relative Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/search_bg" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_searchfilters"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/search_list_selector" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_filter_button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_searchfilters"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And everytime a row would be deleted or added I would just call `LayoutUtils.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(mSearchListView);` which I had defined as :

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
            if (listAdapter == null) {
                // pre-condition
                return;
            }

            int totalHeight = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
                listItem.measure(0, 0);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
            listView.requestLayout();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This looks like an interesting solution.  I will have to try it out.