# Implement LoadMore Button in Listview

Tags: android, listview, button

It's quite a common question but still I'm unable to implement it. In my application, I'm fetching `Inbox messages` and displaying them in `ListView`. Code is working fine but onStartup it loads all messages from inbox to listview. But I want when application starts it loads only `first 15 message` after that a button having label `LoadMore` will show and when clicking button next 15 messages will add to listview. Here's my code snippet:

```
listViewSMS=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvSMS); 
listViewSMS.setAdapter(smsListAdapter);
getInboxSms();
smsListAdapter = new SMSListAdapter(this,populateSMSList());
    listViewSMS.setAdapter(smsListAdapter);

public void getInboxSms() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    c = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    totalSMS = c.getCount();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {
            Log.d("SMSss", "Contact number : "+ c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"))+ "\n"
                            + "msg : " + c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")
                            + "\n"+ "Person : "
                            + getContactName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"))));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}

private List<SMSListModel> populateSMSList() 
{
    if(c.getCount()>0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
        {
            if(c.moveToPosition(i))
            {

                if(getContactName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"))) == null )
                {
                    list.add(new SMSListModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"))));

                }
                }
        }
    }
    return list;        
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: I think you can use `setFooter` for your listView, one another way is handling on `getView` method, see this for first suggest  ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-a-footer-in-listview )

Comment: @ Jeremy D code is working fine... I just want to use `loadmore` button for listview

Comment: @shayan pourvatan Thanks, I've tried implementing `setFooter` but I'm new to android, and I don't know what code to write for the same. Can you help with the code

Comment: see the link that i post, complete answer is there

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Adapter (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html). First, create a list with the 15 first messages and set use it in your adapter and set use setAdapter() on your ListView object. When a user clicks your button you just create a new list with some more elements and then a new adapter and you set it to your listview.

Comment: I think you don't get OPs mean, he/she wants to add more button after `listView`, Adapter is exist if you lock on code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LoadMoreButton](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/) simple tutorial, which describes your goal step by step.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Listview.setOnScrollListener

```
ListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // checking up n down

                    }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            flag_end_show = false;
            if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
            {
                flag_end_show = true;
                if(flag_loading == false)
                {
                    flag_loading = true;

                        new LoadMoreAsync().execute();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: onStartup does it load all inbox messages and what is `new LoadMoreAsync().execute()`. Thanks

Comment: its nothing but calling a function for getting more data...

you have to use pagination , i,e first load 20-30 messages , if user scrolls to bottom of the list if have to get next 20-30 messages and set them to adapter .