# How to add a item to Listview but always make it the last item?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am going to manually add one item to the listView but i always want that item to be the last item in the listview because i am already adding items the listView dynamically

here is what i am using to add the items:

```
tableItems.Add(new TableItem("Test","Test",Resource.Drawable.Icon));
```

Comment: keep datamodel for listview of a ArrayList as they keep track of how elements are added

Answer (score 0):

you should use your custom adapter.
In your adapter, create Add method and make the new item as the last item of ArrayObject or another way make sure that method `getItem (int position)` return the item you had added with `position == (arrayObject.size - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `listView.setFooterView(footerView);` like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4265324/4714139).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add data in your listview adapter and need to notify your adapter.
i.e.

```
  _youAdapter.add("ABC");
    _youAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Your data will add in listview at the end of the list always.

Answer (score 0):

Notify your adapter after this line

```
tableItems.Add(new TableItem("Test","Test",Resource.Drawable.Icon));
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChnaged();
```

if in any case this not work then directly add item to adapter ie.

mAdapter.Add(new TableItem("Test","Test",Resource.Drawable.Icon));
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChnaged();