# how to add fixed button and edittext to bottom of screen

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom ListView.
I want to add a fixed button on the bottom of the screen.

How should I change my layout?

My screen XML code:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ListAdapter" >

    <ImageView
        ... />

    <TextView
        ... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My custom arrayAdapter source code:

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.msg_detail_layout, parent, false);
    msgBodyCustomer = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.MsgBodyCustomer);
    contactImageCustomer = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.PhotoImageCustomer);
    if(!smslist.get(position).getType().equals(INBOX)){
        msgBodyOwner.setText(smslist.get(position).getBody()); 
       contactImageCustomer .setImageURI((smslist.get(position).getPicture()));
    return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: try parent bottom true

Comment: Where is your `ListView`? Do you wanna add the botton on the bottom of `ListView` or out of it, I mean on bottom of the `Relativelayout`.

Comment: sorry you gave us wrong layout, you gave us the item layout not the layout containig listView

Comment: @CharefEddineMechalikh my custom listview have 2 att: ImageView & TextView

Comment: @Lennon  "I mean on bottom of the Relativelayout" => Right.

Comment: so just add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in the `Button` xml code

Answer (score 0):

Edited:try this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ListAdapter" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView7"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/PhotoImageOwner"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button5" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: aaa so this layout is a list item !!

Comment: post your activity layout that contains the listview

Comment: @LMT Try to insert that button code in your activity layout, if its parent layout is Relative it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can add `footer` for your `custom listview`

The footer will always be at bottom

**Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="7dip"
    android:paddingBottom="7dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/footer_image" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
     />

    <TextView 
        android:text="@string/footer_text_1" 
        android:id="@+id/footer_text" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Refer above in your java file `onCreate()` where you are initialising your listview:

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
<your_list_view>.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Reference credit to : [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4265324/1994950)