# ListView and Button(android)

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-styles

I want to make to the listView with an increase fell button: 
[image: Drawing of what I want]

My attempt at implementing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#214075"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listbascet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dip" 
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendtoEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Заказать услуги" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so you want to add elements to the listview?

Comment: what result you get from the xml? I recommend to use RelativeLayout in this case. Make sure Button is below the Listview by using android:layout_below="@+id/your_list_view_id". And you set the layout_height for ListView to 0dip, it means you don't want to show it? I think you would like to set it to wrap_content

Comment: Inlined picture, removed greeting-ish stuff.

Comment: @xwhyLikeThis its result my xml http://s22.postimg.org/ygpo9g169/image.png

Comment: @SebastianWalla yes, i want add element to listView, and button lower down

Comment: Try @xwhyLikeThis suggestion. Change your overall layout type from `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`, set height to `wrap_content`, and set your button to `layout_below` your `ListView`

Comment: @pot34731I see the problem, this result in the button been always fell to bottom right? I think the problem is you set android:layout_weight="1" for the listview. According to android document, layout_weight for listview bigger than the button means the listview will always expand to take up the rest space in the screen. So maybe you just remove the layout_weight property for both of the views.

Comment: Can you remove android:layout_weight="0" from Button and see what result you get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would better remove the button from the XML and add it to another one.

Then you can use the **inflate** to get the button and **add it as footer view** to the original list view.

This way it will be at the end of the list and scroll will it as well!

How to inflate:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                     getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);

Button item = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.item); // how to reference your button
```

How to add footer:

```
listView.addFooterView(view); // view is the inflated layout.
```

More details about footer view contained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4265324/944070)  answer as well.