# How to achieve two sections below listview where i can place dynamic radiobuttons

Tags: android

How can I achieve two sections below listview where I can place dynamic radio buttons, [image: Below is my image]. The listview can be scrollable to an extent, and below that there will be layouts divided into two parts for radiobuttons to fit dynamically

Below is my layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/some_text"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/findSelected"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Find countries that are Selected" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-a-footer-in-listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [weighted propertie](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) and horizontal LinearLayout as footer. Your code should looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/some_text"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/findSelected"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Find countries that are Selected" />

    <!-- Below attributes (layout_height and layout_weight) to fill as much as possible -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"/> 


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <!-- Content of the column 1 -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <!-- Content of the column 2 -->
        </LinearLayout> 
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```