# Layout with a ListView

Tags: android

I have a Activity with a layout that is a Vertical LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout, ListView, and another RelativeLayout. My problem is if the ListView is longer than the screen, the bottom RelativeLayout will be unreachable. How can I ensure the last RelativeLayout is always at the end of the ListView? Can I make it part of the ListView somehow?

Comment: Share your layout design code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the Bottom `RelativeLayout` to be fixed use the root element as `RelativeLayout` and use `alignParentBottom = true` to bottom `RelativeLayout` and position `ListView` below top relative layout and above bottom `relativelayout`.

if the bottom `Relativelayout` has to scroll as you scroll `listview` add it as a `footer` to the `listview`.Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4265324/4321808) on how to add a `footer` to `listview`.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to use recyclerview instead of ListVIew