# Adding textview below each group of items in listview

Tags: android, listview

First of all,I am sorry if my question is meaningless or wrong.

> I need to add `textview` as the `footer view` to `listview` ,and that
>   footer view should be repeated for particular number of items.

For example,

If I am having 50 items in a list, whenever I am displaying it in `listview` , the `textview` should be displayed below the each group of 10 items (That is the textview should separate 10 items).

Can anyone help me please. I don't even know "using footer view to achieve this is right or not". Thanks!

Comment: You can add footerview to listview have a look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/4265324/4824088

Comment: @Joe what you have tried so far? Please post the code

Comment: If above solution works with fixed footerview if you want n no of seperator add custom view in between the position(11,21,31,41) using adapter class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `@Override getItemViewType` and return 2 type of views based on the position (you set a condition there). Also, in `onBindViewHolder` (if you use a Recyclerview, and I suggest you to do that) you will check which view was returned and what data to fetch.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type) should help you understand perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, I just add textview to the layout and make it visible when the condition is satisfied in my adapter.

Comment: Sure, you could do that, but you might find that sometimes doesn't work as you expected, and here I mean upon scrolling. But is your call,
Glad I could help

Comment: yeah,if number of items is increased in listview, It doesn't work as what i need :(

Comment: So go for my solution, I used same thing on a `RecyclerView` for a chat actually. Had two cases, `message received` and `message sent`. Number of items was changing and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

First @override below function in your adapter

```
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0) return 1;
        else return 2;
    }
 }
```

After that check returning positions in @onBindViewHolder and manage your data according to that.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: how can I use those returned values? I am using listview. Could you explain?

Comment: Use this in adapter class of your listview @Joe