# Change layout of last item in Android Listview ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

So currently I'm using an ArrayAdapter to populate my listview from my database, like so:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, R.layout.subject_list_item, mArrayList);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

(mArrayList is a list of the text that will populate the listview, lv.)

Currently, if I want to add a final item to the bottom of the list, I can just append it to the `mArrayList`, but this will set it's layout to `subject_list_item` the same as all the other items. Is there an easy way of setting the `layout` of only the final item to a different layout, say `subject_list_item2`? I want it in the same list so that it still scrolls with the other items, but I want it to look different.

Comment: @ADM yeah, the top answer to that is definitely what I wanted, cheers. I don't know if I should close this question however, considering the uncertainty in the responses to the question you've linked over whether the user wanted the footer to scroll or not. I'll just accept the answer that links to the relevant answer on that question.

Comment: Do the right thing!!!  Mark it as duplicate ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a footer in your listview (I am assuming your lv means it is a ListView).

Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4265324/783707

To summarize, use this code:

```
    View footer =  getActivity().inflate(R.layout.footer, null, false);
    lv.addFooterView(footer);
```