# How to add a footer to android menu drawer (navigation view)

Tags: android, xml, layout

Just like I can add header I want to be able to add a footer. My main problem is that I can add a button to the bottom of the drawer, but when screen is too small menu drawer items scroll behind that button. I want so that button moves along with those items and is always positioned at the bottom. I added Button to the navigation view and menu items separately in xml file.

Comment: Update question with xml file of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct support in `NavigationView` to add footer . You can  remove navigation view and a `ListView` in place of it and add header and footer to ListView .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView_nav"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

check how to add footer to listView [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-a-footer-in-listview)

Comment: I just used scrollview with linearlayout and added elements inside of it. It worked like that.

Answer (score 0):

Make header height and width matching the parent and in header layout you can customize all the content as you want.

Comment: I wanted footer not header.