# How to set the header and footer for linear layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Can anybody tell me how to set a fixed header and footer for relative layout and center point? I want to add scrollable and adding array of webview dynamically when I want to scroll center point only scrollable in android. Can anybody give an example?

I tried but center part webview is not appearing properly, is there anything to change?

my xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:id="@+id/mainrelativelayout"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/linear1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

  >

<TextView  android:paddingRight="75dip" android:paddingLeft="20dip" android:text="Index" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
<TextView android:paddingRight="60dip"   android:text="Last" android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
<TextView  android:text="Change" android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:id="@+id/linear1" android:layout_height="6dip"
     android:orientation="horizontal"

   >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView08" android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/line" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/linear2"
  android:orientation="horizontal"

  >
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView05" android:paddingTop="5dip" android:layout_gravity="center"  android:background="@drawable/down" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
 <TextView  android:paddingRight="30dip" android:paddingLeft="10dip"   android:text="" android:id="@+id/txtindex0" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
<TextView  android:paddingRight="55dip"  android:text="" android:id="@+id/txtlast0" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
<TextView     android:text="" android:id="@+id/txtchange0" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="12dip" android:textColor="@color/red1"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/linear3"
  android:orientation="horizontal"

  >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView02" android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/up" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
<TextView  android:paddingRight="46dip"  android:paddingLeft="10dip"    android:text="" android:id="@+id/txtindex1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
<TextView  android:paddingRight="64dip"  android:text="" android:id="@+id/txtlast1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
<TextView  android:text="" android:id="@+id/txtchange1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="12dip" android:textColor="@color/green1"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/linear4"
   android:orientation="horizontal"

  >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView03" android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/up" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
<TextView  android:paddingRight="69dip"  android:paddingLeft="10dip"  android:text="" android:id="@+id/txtindex2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
<TextView  android:paddingRight="67dip"  android:text="" android:id="@+id/txtlast2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
<TextView  android:text="" android:id="@+id/txtchange2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="12dip" android:textColor="@color/green1"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/linear4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

  >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView04" android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/up" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
<TextView  android:paddingRight="61dip" android:paddingLeft="10dip"   android:text="" android:id="@+id/txtindex3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
<TextView  android:paddingRight="65dip"  android:text="" android:id="@+id/txtlast3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
<TextView  android:text="" android:id="@+id/txtchange3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="12dip" android:textColor="@color/green1"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:id="@+id/linear1" android:layout_height="4dip"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
      >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView08" android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/line" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="15dip"
  android:id="@+id/linear5"
  android:orientation="horizontal"

  >
<TextView android:text="Market data delayed at least 15 minutes " android:id="@+id/TextView16" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="12dip" android:textColor="@color/gray2"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<------ finishing header-------->
```

<---------- adding footer----------->

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/imglinear"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView15" android:src="@drawable/quest_i" android:layout_gravity="center"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

<--------------finishing footer------->

<------------ center point of screen--------->

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:id="@+id/mainlinear3"
  android:layout_above="@+id/imglinear"
  android:layout_below="@+id/mainlinear2"
   >
  <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">  
 <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:id="@+id/relative3">

  </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

<-----------center point finishing---------->

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to use `Linearlayout`. Use `RelativeLayout`

Comment: You may want to use a mix of multiple layout elements, not just one LinearLayout. and please elaborate your question, add any screen-shot of what you would like to see.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- HEADER -->
    <include android:id="@+id/top_header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" layout="@layout/layout_header" />


    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bottom_menu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <!-- menu bar -->
        <include layout="@layout/layout_footer_menu" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- MAIN PART -->
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_header" android:layout_above="@id/bottom_menu"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/sub_content_view"
        android:paddingBottom="5sp" android:background="#EAEAEA">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It is better to set to MAIN PART both:

android:layout_below="@id/top_header" 
android:layout_above="@id/bottom_menu"

In your case content will be under the footer and scroll bar will be shown incorrect.

Also you need place footer in code above content - android want see ID's (@id/bottom_menu) if it wasn't define before.

Comment: is there any way in android to add footer for whole application, like if I add a footer in first activity at bottom, now if I move to second activity, third activity and so on....the footer will still there which I've added in the first activity. (same like in iPhone Navigation controller is used)