# How to set header and footer in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, header, footer

I have an Application in which I want to set header and footer for specific layout.

Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Header and footer of what?? is it `ListView`, any specific layout or the whole application

Comment: Check the link below : http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1764 Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732634/how-to-set-the-header-and-footer-for-linear-layout-in-android

Comment: make a layout for header and another for footer. whenever you want to use header footer just include them in your layout using `<include>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `RelativeLayout` and attributes as below:

For header:
`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

For footer:
`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`