# Creating Header on A Screen(Activity)

Tags: android, header, android-activity, footer

1. All I want to do is creating a simple header and footer in my android activity(Screen). I have used `RelativeLayout` in my UI.
2. And also if I wanted to add a popup Menu in header how would I do that.

Please answer both question separately. Thanks

Comment: Point 1) 

possible duplicate of <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732634/how-to-set-the-header-and-footer-for-linear-layout-in-android>

Point 2)
There are several ways to do that:
- PopupMenu Class (see android Docs) <http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html>
- Create custom dialog (see android Docs)

Answer (score 0):

```
For Header You can make an activity_header.xml Class. & it will include in other classes like as-



<include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/activity_header" />


& for Footer you can use Tab Bar:-
see this:-
http://www.technotalkative.com/android-tab-bar-example-1/
```

Comment: that i have found already to include . What should be code of activity_header.xml??

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use like as:activity_header.xml Or You can use RelativeLayout  for this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_header_icon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/header_logo" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: first I have created this file in layout folder .. Then I have included it in xml file of my Main activity but no header is shown